# How to delete a value from enum

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an enum and I want to modify that enum and delete one of its value.

```
enum Location {a, b, c}
```

I want to use the same enum later on in the code but I want to delete the `a` from Location.  How can I do that in Flutter?

After deleted the `a` the enum Location will be look like this

```
Location {b, c}
```

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense to me. What effect do you think that deleting this value has?

Comment: Maybe I should use a different type of variable, I thought enum I can modify its value later on like an array.

Answer (score 3):

Enum is fixed number of known constant instances. All instances of the enum must be declared in the beginning of the declaration. So we can't add/delete values from a enum

Answer (score 1):

I don't know dart, but assuming that enum is an immutable value, just create a function that accepts your enum with a, and constructs a new enum that doesn't include the a.

If you're from Clojure the idea would be something like: `(dissoc a Location)`.

Forgive me if I'm spouting nonesense. Let me know and I'll remove the answer.

Comment: I have that idea as well, I'll try that.

Answer (score 1):

enums generally cannot be modified as they represent fixed set of values, just define another enum and use it for what you want to achieve e.g

enum Location { b, c }

Comment: nice, you give me an idea now.  I should create new enum like this:  `enum newLocation {Location.a, Location.b, Location.c }`
I can still use the Location enum in that way.

Comment: Yes exactly you can as well do it this way.